# Django Admin Queryset Filter OR

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset

I'm using django-admin and I'm overriding queryset to filter my objects. I was wondering if it was possible to do an OR filter, i.e. return the object if a is True or if b is True.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just use Q objects and | to combine them.

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def queryset(self, request):
        return super(MyAdmin, self).queryset(request).filter(Q(a=True) | Q(b=True))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Since (a | b) is logically equivalent to ~(~a & ~b) you can also express this with `.exclude`:

```
return super(MyAdmin, self).queryset(request).exclude(a=False, b=False)
```

Which is clearer depends a bit on what your actual comparison is.  And if you've got nullable terms you have to remember that comparisons to null always return False - not a problem for a simple boolean, but it can bite you if you have, say, a nullable numeric field and try to negate a comparison or range.